# PHP - HTML parsing (property of non object )

Tags: php, html, parsing

I'm parsing a html page code to get 'a' tags values (href)

I'm doing this like that:

```
$doc2 = loadPage( $item_link ); echo    '_(item)' . PHP_EOL; 
$item_links = $doc2->getElementsByTagName('a');
$items = [];

    foreach($item_links as $item) {

        $linkurl2 = $item->attributes->getNamedItem('href')->value;
        echo $linkurl2 . PHP_EOL;
        if(preg_match("/^..\/thekey\//", $linkurl)) $items[] .= $linkurl2;
    }
```

and in general everythings going fine, exept on some links I'm getting PHP Notice, which one I'm can't realy understand.:

```
PHP Notice:  Trying to get property of non-object in /home/user/http/code/lFile/bashpr.php on line 60

http://www.amazon.com/gp/search?ie=UTF8&keywords=keywords&tag=indexed&index=music&linkCode=ur2&camp=1789&creative=5152
```

This is the 'echo' output from previous paste above. But whats wrong with this item? In html code it looks just like any other tag:

```
<a href="http://www.amazon.com/gp/search?ie=UTF8&keywords=keywords&tag=indexed&index=music&linkCode=ur2&camp=1789&creative=5152" rel="external">
<img width="30" height="18" src="http://images.link.com/image.png" alt="buy this CD or download MP3s at amazon.com!">
</a>
```

any other links are without 'img' tag, is this, what is about?

Comment: Which line is line #60 ?

Comment: $linkurl2 = $item->attributes->getNamedItem('href')->value;

Comment: In this line, or $item, or $item->attributes or $item->attributes->getNamedItem('href') is not a object. Try debugging here to find out where is your problem.

Comment: I know it is in this line. I paste the failure tag, what else can be debugged?